# Debian : Verify disk encryption password for already mounted system

Tags: debian, encryption, raid, mdadm

I am working on our Debian server on which we have a Raid drive encrypted with 2 devices. I did this around 1.5 years back and have never rebooted since. Now, we want to reboot for some reasons, but I have to make sure that the password I have is the correct one, or we will be stuck.

How can we verify the password for an encrypted-raid? Thank you.

Raid details :

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0   
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Feb 11 14:43:40 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953382336 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382336 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Mar 10 10:37:42 2017
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : HOSTNAME:0  (local to host HOSTNAME)
           UUID : 5c450558:44a2b1e9:83cb4361:9c74df8e
         Events : 49

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Thank you.

*Update*

```
dmsetup table --showkeys
CryptVol: 0 Large_Number crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 RANDOM_TEXT  0 253:0 4096
RaidVG-LVMVol: 0 Large_Number linear 9:0 2048
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mdadm` does not encrypt, so what did you use? LUKS?

With LUKS you can just see if `cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/md0` or similar will accept your password. Otherwise, if the container is still open, do a `dmsetup table --showkeys` that gives you all the parameters and master key which allows you to circumvent LUKS...

I guess the correct way to test is

```
cryptsetup --test-passphrase luksOpen /dev/luksdevice

   --test-passphrase
          Do not activate device, just verify passphrase.  This option  is
          only  relevant  for  open action (the device mapping name is not
          mandatory if this option is used).
```

But I usually just use `luksAddKey` ;) who knows, maybe you actually do want to add another backup passphrase in case you forget one of them. Or add the same passphrase in two different keyboard layouts (if you do not use US keyboard by default).

Comment: I tried the 2nd command you gave me, I have added part of its output in bottom of main post, can you please check. Thanks.

Comment: For your 1st command, I get /dev/md0 is not a valid LUKS device.

Comment: Oh, so encrypted LV... `/dev/dm-0` (or its alias `/dev/RaidVG/LVMVol` or `/dev/mapper/RaidVG-LVMVol` or whatever)

Comment: I dont understand what you want to say, but I just removed large string in it, thinking it might be the key.

Comment: … use /dev/dm-0 instead of /dev/md0 for the first command. And write down the full output of dmsetup for yourself, if you really don't know the passphrase, that's your only ticket to the data. Better yet make a full backup while it's still running

Comment: This seems to be working, although it shows no key available with this passphrase, we are waiting for key from admin, will get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the command terminates when the password is correct?

Comment: If there is no output, append `&& echo OK || echo FAIL` then try with the passphrase you believe is correct and with an invalid passphrase... there should be a difference. There's also `cryptsetup --verbose`